# Web service not responding properly.After restarting the app pool it works

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have hosted web service in IIS and it's working normally. But sometimes it's not responding properly. Then I restarted the app pool and then it's working fine. This issue happens 2, 3 times in a week.

What will be the solution?

Comment: Many things could cause this. It is impossible to guess without more information. You need to do more research. Watch for resource leaks (memory, handles, queues, threads, objects). Also, it might help if we could see the code, to spot mistakes (like if you forget to dispose objects or close connections or files, or leave orphaned threads, etc). a

Comment: Also, check your NT Event logs. See if any warnings or errors occur within 1 hour of your process hang. Also watch traffic: could it be a denial-of-service or heavy traffic (infinite loop, etc)

Comment: Until you solve it, some people try to treat a problem like this by setting the application pool to auto-restart every day (or more frequently). Sometimes it helps and sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: Open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com so that you can work with them. Typical approach is https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/919792/how-to-use-the-debug-diagnostics-tool-to-troubleshoot-a-process-that-h but not trivial for beginners.

Comment: Okay. I will check with code and server logs.